# What's the correct way to subclass AppCompatButton?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-appcompat

```
// FooButton.kt
class FooButton : AppCompatButton {
    @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
        : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int)
        : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) // Nope
}
```

Everything's fine when subclassing AppCompatTextView but not AppCompatButton, even though
both inherit [`View`'s signature](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int)) so subclasses can have their own base styles. Which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

I get an error at the Lollipop constructor's `super` call that no functions can be called with the arguments supplied. [`AppCompatButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html)! What makes you so special?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation for AppCompatButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html), `AppCompatButton` **does not** have a 4 argument constructor, despite View having a 4 argument constructors - constructors are treated differently from methods.